# Make a thread-safe list of integers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety

I need to make a class that stores a List of int and read/write from it asynchronously.

here's my class:

```
public class ConcurrentIntegerList
{
    private readonly object theLock = new object();
    List<int> theNumbers = new List<int>();

    public void AddNumber(int num)
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            theNumbers.Add(num);
        }
    }

    public List<int> GetNumbers()
    {
       lock (theLock)
       {
         return theNumbers;
       }
    }
}
```

But it is not thread-safe until here. when I do multiple operations from different threads I get this error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

What I missed here?

Comment: You're locking in `GetNumbers` is pointless. Someone could call it and add a number to the returned list, circumventing your locking in `AddNumber`

Comment: Where is your requirement coming from? Is this homework? If not, you can look at Concurrent Collections (ConcurrentBag for example)

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos yes kinda, they said me don't use those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<int> GetNumbers()
{
    lock (theLock)
    {
      // return theNumbers;
         return theNumbers.ToList();
    }
}
```

But the performance won't be very good this way, and GetNumbers() now returns a snapshot copy.

Comment: ? `theNumbers` is already a List. Why would that help?

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos - calling `ToList` will make a copy of the list.